# Update Link Plugin in RTE Touch UI

Tags: aem

I am looking for overriding the features of Link plugin in RTE, Touch UI. Basic feature I want to override root path, that by default is `"/content/mysite/en"` to `"/content"`.

Its always points to "Website" . I want to select document from DAM

[image]

Other is I want to disable the auto-select feature of modify-link option.

Do someone have the idea to achieve this in TOUCH UI. In Classic i can do via changing LinkDialog.js but in Touch UI which will the file I need to change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Links plugin in RTE for touch UI. There is a inplace editing plugin for specific purpose

[image]

And enabling/disabling features is as simple as what plugins are we adding under the edit config. Hope this helps.

Comment: Whats the default location opens once you click on magnifier glass? Are you able to select documents from DAM?

Comment: Yes. It opens the /content path and shows its immediate children. I am able to select documents from DAM as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the links plugin, you can find it here: `/libs/cq/ui/rte/core/plugins/LinkPlugin.js` editing that is not recommended, you might want to create a new plugin that overrides this one and add the root directory you want.